# exporting html tables to ms word

Tags: php, javascript, phpdocx

I have a html table in this format:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I have a download button:

```
<input type="text" name="download" value="Download">
```

I need this table to be exported/downloaded in ms word format when user clicks on the Download button. Please help me with the codes to achieve this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://codecanyon.net/item/javascript-excel-creator/5031884?WT.ac=category_item&WT.seg_1=category_item&WT.z_author=hotblue

Comment: Try some freelancer sites to get help **with the codes to achieve this** We don't code for each other on SO instead we help each other to code or to debug.

Answer (score 3):

you may try the simple solution in setting your script header

```
 header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=YOUR_DOC_NAME.doc"); 

echo '<table>....';
```

that will force your user to download all the echo into ms-word document

Answer (score 0):

Here's a library called [phpdocx](http://www.phpdocx.com/) that can be used from PHP. There's even [a page about converting HTML to docx](http://www.phpdocx.com/documentation/html-to-word-PHP). The code there looks something like this:

```
require_once 'pathToPHPDocX/classes/CreateDocx.inc';

$docx = new CreateDocx();

$html='<p>some html</p>';

$docx->embedHTML($html);

$docx->createDocx('simpleHTML');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: http://phpword.codeplex.com/

Its work. I'm using it too

Answer (score -1):

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.msword");
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=sampleword.doc");
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wg2eaqIEeYY